# Accessing variable by string name

Tags: matlab, octave, scilab

I need to load experimental data into *scicoslab*, a (pretty badly designed) <strike>clone</strike> fork of *scilab* which happens to support graphical modeling. The documentation on the web is pretty poor, but it's reasonably similar to *scilab* and *octave*.

The data I need to process is contained into a certain number of text files: `Data_005`, `Data_010`, …, `Data_100`. Each of them can be loaded using the *-ascii* flag for the `loadmatfile` command.

The problem comes from the fact that `loadmatfile("foo", "-ascii")` loads the file `foo.mat` into a variable named `foo`. In order to to cycle on the data files, I would need to do something like:

```
for i = [5:5:100]
    name = sprintf("Data_%02d", i);
    loadmatfile(name, "-ascii");
    x = read_var_from_name(name);
    do_something(x);
end
```

where what I search for is a builtin `read_var_from_name` which would allow me to access the internal symbol table by string.

Do you know if there exist a similar function?

**Notes:**

1. There's no way of overriding this behavior if your file is in *ascii* format;
2. In this phase I could also use octave (no graphical modelling is involved), although it behaves in the same way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
>> foo = 3.14; name = 'foo'; eval(name)

foo =

    3.1400
```

The above works in MATLAB, and Scilab's documentation says it also has an `eval` function. Not sure if I understood you correctly, though.

Answer (score 9):

@arne.b has a good answer.

In your case you can also do that in matlab:

```
a=load('filename.mat')
x=a.('variable_name')
```

Comment: Just wanted to say (as someone from a programming background where `eval()` is considered evil) thanks for pointing this out; I had no idea this syntax existed!

Comment: @miken32 `eval` is indeed evil.

Answer (score 0):

lets go through your points one by one:

1. "ScicosLab, a (pretty badly designed) clone of Scilab" This in my opinion is an inaccurate way of introducing the software. ScicosLab is not a clone of Scilab but a fork of it. The team behind ScicosLab (INRIA) are the ones who made scocos (now called xcos in Scilab development line). At some point (from Scilab v4) the Scilab team decided to move away from Tcl/tk towards Java, but the SciccosLab/scicos team departed, keep using the language (Tcl) and it's graphical user interface design package (tk). Giving the ScocosLab community the credit that the whole Scilab documentation and support is not very good in general. :) (more about Scilab and the forks [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/b6gn9r/nsp_is_a_gpl_scientific_software_package/))
2. Regarding the technical question I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here, Scilab/ScicosLab still have the `eval` function which basically does what you want.  However this function is to be deprecated in favor of `evstr`. There is also the `execstr` function which worth studying.
3. The `loadmatfile`, as far as I have understood, "tries" to load the variables defined in a MATLAB `.mat` file (MATLAB's proprietary tabular format) into the Scilab workspace. For example if there is a variable `foo` it will "try" to create the variable `foo` and loads its value from the MATLAB script. Check this [example](https://help.scilab.org/doc/6.0.0/en_US/loadmatfile.html). I would create a variable `x(i) = foo` in the for loop. again your question is not completely clear.
4. As a side note maybe you could consider exporting your data as CSV instead of `.mat` files.